# Print DataTable Headers in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jsf-2

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<h:dataTable value="#{personBean.addresses}" var="address" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
     <h:column>
         <f:facet name="header">Postcode</f:facet><br/>
         <h:outputText value="#{address.postcode}" />
     </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Can anyone tell me why this prints the header for each row instead of just printing the header once off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{personBean.addresses}" var="address" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
   <h:outputText value="Postcode" />
 </f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{address.postcode}" />
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: NetBeans warns me: `#{...} not allowed in a template text body.` and when I run it, I get the error `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /results.jsp(72,30) PWC6228: #{...} not allowed in a template text body.`

Comment: Thanks, it did work. Just one question though, do you know why `<h:outputText value="#{address.postcode}" />` is not styled as well when I use `<h:column headerClass="col1">`?

Comment: Use style : <h:outputText value="#{address.postcode}" style="font-weight:bold" />